# MATLAB: save arabic string in .txt file

Tags: matlab

I am working on a steganography project involving Arabic characters and have written a MATLAB function called 'stegoText'. The function reads two UTF-8 encoded text files, 'secretmessage.txt' and 'covermessage.txt', and performs the following steps:

- Converts Arabic characters to binary using a mapping table of UNICODE values to binary
- Converts binary to DNA
- Converts DNA to RNA by replacing T with U and adding a start and stop codon
- Performs Huffman compression on the RNA sequence
- Embeds the encoded string into an Arabic cover message
- Writes the result to 'stego.txt' using UTF-16LE encoding

The function works well but the resulting 'stego.txt' file appears disordered. How can I fix this?

Here's how they differ between what I see on MATLAB and in the .txt file:
[image]
[image]

Here is the MATLAB code:

```matlab
function stego = stegoText() 

file_path = 'C:\Users\Charbel\Desktop\secretmessage.txt';
secret = fileread(file_path);

file_path = 'C:\Users\Charbel\Desktop\covermessage.txt';
cover = fileread(file_path);

% Part A: Dealing with the arabic secret message 

% Step 1: Convert from Arabic to Binary

% Mapping table for arabic characters to binary using UNICODE

mappingTable = table();

mappingTable.Arabic = ['ن'; 'ح'; 'ط'; 'ف'; 'ش'; 'ا'; 'ي'; 'ر'; 'و'; 'ك'; 'د'; 'ت'; 'ز'; 'ع'; ...
    'م'; 'ص'; 'ج'; 'ه'; 'س'; 'ب'; 'ذ'; 'ض'; 'غ'; 'ظ'; 'ث'; 'ق'; 'خ'; 'ل'; ...
    ' '; '،'; '؛'; '.'; '9'; '8'; '7'; '4'; '1'; '6'; '0'; '2'; '5'; '3'; '؟'; 'َ'; 'ِ'; 'ؤ'; ...
    'ُ'; 'ة'; 'ى'; 'ْ'; '٠'; '١'; '٣'; '٤'; '٥'; '٦'; '٧'; '٨'; '٩'; ...
    'ء'; 'ئ'; ':'; '!'; '٢'];

mappingTable.Binary = ['000000'; '000001'; '000010'; '000011'; '000100'; '000101'; '000110'; '000111'; ...
    '001000'; '001001'; '001010'; '001011'; '001100'; '001101'; '001110'; '001111'; '010000'; '010001'; ...
    '010010'; '010011'; '010100'; '010101'; '010110'; '010111'; '011000'; '011001'; '011010'; '011011'; ...
    '011100'; '011101'; '011110'; '011111'; '100000'; '100001'; '100010'; '100011'; '100100'; '100101'; ...
    '100110'; '100111'; '101000'; '101001'; '101010'; '101011'; '101100'; '101101'; '101110'; '101111'; ...
    '110000'; '110001'; '110010'; '110011'; '110101'; '110110'; '110111'; '111000'; '111001'; ...
    '111010'; '111011'; '111100'; '111100'; '111101'; '111111'; '110100'];

secretBinary = '';

for i = 1:length(secret)
    index = find(mappingTable.Arabic == secret(i));
    binaryChar = mappingTable.Binary(index, :);
    secretBinary = [secretBinary binaryChar];
end

% Step 2: Convert from Binary to DNA

dnaStrand = '';

for i = 1:2:length(secretBinary)
    segment = secretBinary(i:i+1);
    switch segment
        case '00'
            dnaBase = 'A';
        case '01'
            dnaBase = 'C';
        case '10'
            dnaBase = 'G';
        case '11'
            dnaBase = 'T';
    end
    dnaStrand = [dnaStrand dnaBase];
end

% Step 3: Convert from DNA to RNA (replace T by U, add start and stop codons)

rnaStrand = strrep(dnaStrand, 'T', 'U');

startCodon = 'AUG';
stopCodon = ['UAA'; 'UAG'; 'UGA'];

randomIndex = randi([1, 3]);

rnaStrand = [startCodon rnaStrand stopCodon(randomIndex, :)];

% Step 4: Huffmann compression 

numericArray = double(rnaStrand);

symbols = unique(numericArray);
probabilities = ones(size(symbols)) / numel(symbols);

huffDict = huffmandict(symbols, probabilities);
save('huffman_dictionary.mat', 'huffDict');

encodedData = huffmanenco(numericArray, huffDict);

encodedString = char(encodedData + '0');

% Part B: Embedding the encoded string into the arabic cover message

% Step 1: Get the size of the encoded secret message, and the size of the cover message

sizeSecret = length(encodedString);
sizeCover = length(cover);

% Step 2: Embed the encodedString into the cover message

stego = '';

if sizeCover < sizeSecret
    stego = 'Cover message is not long enough';
else
    for i = 1:sizeSecret
        bit = encodedString(i);
        coverChar = cover(i);

        if i == 1 && isletter(coverChar)
            if bit == '1'
                stego = [stego coverChar char(hex2dec('200D'))];
            else
                stego = [stego coverChar char(hex2dec('FEFF'))];
            end

        elseif i > 1 && ~isletter(cover(i-1)) && isletter(coverChar)
            if bit == '1'
                stego = [stego coverChar char(hex2dec('200D'))];
            else
                stego = [stego coverChar char(hex2dec('FEFF'))];
            end

        elseif isletter(coverChar) && i < sizeCover && isletter(cover(i+1))
            if bit == '1'
                stego = [stego coverChar char(hex2dec('200E'))];
            else
                stego = [stego coverChar char(hex2dec('200F'))];
            end

        elseif isletter(coverChar) && (i == sizeCover || ~isletter(cover(i+1)))
            if bit == '1'
                stego = [stego coverChar char(hex2dec('200C'))];
            else
                stego = [stego coverChar char(hex2dec('200B'))];
            end

        elseif ~isletter(coverChar)
            if bit == '1'
                stego = [stego coverChar char(hex2dec('2009'))];
            else
                stego = [stego coverChar char(hex2dec('200A'))];
            end
        end
    end
    stego = [stego cover(length(encodedString)+1:end)];
end

filePath = fullfile('C:', 'Users', 'Charbel', 'Desktop', 'stego.txt');

fileID = fopen(filePath, 'w', 'n', 'UTF-16LE');

fwrite(fileID, stego, 'char', 'n');

fclose(fileID);

end
```

Comment: For us non-Arabic speakers, is this just using a different font, or are they totally different letters? Is the order reversed? Is it using the wrong encoding?

Answer (score 0):

**1.-** You are coding in MATLAB using non-arabic, Western Latin alphabet.

Reading and thus processing files goes from **left to right**.

The most significant part of a sentence, from a reader point of view, is the 1st word.

Yes a lot can be discussed, that grammatically the most important word in any sentence is always the subject, followed by the verb and then adjectives, adverbs, so on so forth.

But no, from a purely communcations point of view we need to start on the 1st word, and then follow on.

The term IT people use is **Big/Little Endian.**

[Endianess intro.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Then you use notepad to open an Arabic encoded message. This goes right to left.

```
                             tfel ot thgiR
                   من اليمين إلى اليسار باللغة العربية
```

The same happens when mixing text edition in Western Latin and **Hebrew**:

```
                           מימין לשמאל בעברית
```

The order of words and characters is shuffled around by 2 systems pushing on opposite directions.

**2.-** Would it be possible for you to work with an Arabic version of MATLAB and do it all left-to-right?

**3.-** Or perhaps keeping it all in same Western Latin alphabet and left-to-right may be another option to consider.

**4.-** Actually, the alphabets mapping between Arabic and Western Latin is **not** exactly one-to-one and therefore, characters may be lost or added in translation.

**5.- Maximize your Audience**

Keeping one version in Western Latin only would increase the amount of Western readers.

Building another working version all in Arabic only would also increase amount of readers among Arabic versed people.

You see, when you publishing things, bilinguals are certainly minorities, compared to non-bilinguals.

You are not targeting your app for bilinguals only, with a Biology degree, and familiar with MATLAB, are you?

**6.-** The equivalent concept in serial communications is : **Least Significant Bit** first, or Most Significant Bit first.